# Calling function within a Function

Tags: javascript, blockly, google-blockly

I have a situation where I generate code from within a Blockly component. The resulting code will have a function that I want to call. According to the [Blockly "Generating and Running JavaScript"](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/app-integration/running-javascript) documentation, I should use `eval()`.

When I look up `eval()` on MSDN, I get a section that I should ["never use eval"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) and use `Function` instead.

Here is some example code from what the output of the code could be:

```js
let blocklyResult = `function onExecute() {
    console.log('Function has been called!');
}`;

let code = new Function(blocklyResult);
```

I want to call the `onExecute` function from within the `code` variable, but I cannot figure out how I can do that?

What is the best way to accomplish my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Function` constructor will generate a function with the string code inside. if the string code come in format of function, the function will generate this function, but you also need to call it. So ether (if you can) pass as a string the code to execute (not function) or add execute the function yourself. like this:

```js
var a = `function onExecute(){console.log('Function has been called')}`
var b = new Function(`(${a})()`);
b();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `Function` document [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Difference_between_Function_constructor_and_function_declaration), you should define function just from code lines, not include something like `function XXXXX() {}`

So, it should be

```js
let blocklyResult = `console.log('Function has been called!')`;
let code = new Function(blocklyResult);

code()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let blocklyResult = `function onExecute() {
    console.log('Function has been called!');
}`;

// v1
let code1 = new Function(`${blocklyResult};onExecute();`);
code1();

// v2
let code2 = (new Function(`return ${blocklyResult}`))();
code2();
```

`v1` creates a new function every time it's called

`v2` returns the function so it can be called multiple times without recreating the blockly function

`v2` is preferable IMO